# Recurring discrepancies in rep

Tags: support, reputation

When I had visited https://math.stackexchange.com/reputation for the first time and seen that it shows lower rep than the main site I triggered rep recalc and forgot about it. When after a while I've seen the effect again I was mildly surprised but triggered recalc again. Now I again see that rep recalc will reduce my rep — and since it would happen for the 3rd time I become wary. Could someone please check that there are no little green men eating my rep? (Speaking more seriously, I don't really suspect a bug, just wonder what's going on.)

Comment: It happens to me from time to time as well. The drop is usually of 15 points, therefore I assume that an answer was unaccepted. It is not possible, at the moment, to find out which answer. Except, of course, to have daily dumps of your reputation sheet and compare when a drop occurs.

Comment: @Asaf I thought unaccepting answer removes 15 points immediately, no? (And in my case drop is more like 40 points, and even more first time, IRC.)

Comment: @Grigory: Maybe a question you answered was deleted.

Comment: @Hendrik Well... yes, maybe. Do you know any way to check, by any chance? (Perhaps, [data explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/) can be used somehow?..)

Comment: @Asaf ([earlier questions](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1934/15-of-reputation-where-to-check-why-closed) seem to confirm my hypothesis)

Comment: Hmm... that just rises further questions. I mean, 15 points are either question votes or accepted answers. I wonder, now, how I lost 15 points, twice, like that.

Comment: @Grigory: The least you need is 10K rep, so I can't really help.

Comment: Another possibility: IIRC when a user that upvoted your stuff is removed from an SE site, the rep s/he gave you is taken away too...

Comment: @J. M. Interesting. (No way to check this hypothesis either, I guess?..)

Comment: Right; that's a rather irritating "feature"...

Comment: @Hendrik Oh, but it's impossible to delete a question with upvoted answer without closing it first, than waiting and then voting to delete (or using moderator superpowers — in case of spam etc), AFAIK. So I don't believe such thing happened many times with questions I answered without me noticing.

Comment: @Grigory: Right, even the infamous "Kalle number" question is still around.

Comment: Somewhat relevant: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90820/20-reputation-why

Answer (score 5):

There have been a handful of troublesome users posting spam whose accounts I have been destroying. One of those users may have posted a question you answered.

Comment: So even moderator can't say anything definite?.. OK, I see.

Comment: The reason I can't say anything definite is that destroyed accounts don't leave any traces in the databases (that I know of), so I can't go back through them and tell you what questions they asked.